# Cannot remove white space between flex items after making them a figure

Tags: html, css

I created a flexbox successfully with some images, and it looked good. I then made the images into figures because I needed to add captions to the images, and white space was introduced that I cannot get rid of.

Here is a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/dawsboss888/pen/qBybXEJ

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ballon">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/250/250618.png">
          <figcaption>2009</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/250/250618.png">
          <figcaption>2011</figcaption>
        </figure>
     
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

img {
  max-width: 25px;
}


figcaption {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center
}

.ballon {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 450px;
  
  
}
```

Comment: Would making the width of the parent container (.container class) smaller fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on the chrome browser figure element seems to have some default margin definitions on your example:

[image]

If these margins are the "whitespaces" you are talking about, then you can get rid of them by adding margin definition in your css file like this:

```
figure {
    margin: 0px;
}
```